# How vim resolve color names in 256-color term?

Tags: vim, colors, 256color

For example,

```
ctermfg=DarkBlue
```

How vim decides the rgb value for the color name `DarkBlue`? It was said that it was described in `$VIMRUNTIME/rgb.txt`. But in some release of vim this file does not exist.

BTW, how vim decides the rgb value for a numeric color, such as

```
ctermfg=0
```

Comment: "But in some release of vim this file does not exist." - Can you be more specific? Which release?

Comment: As for numeric colours, Vim uses the Unix terminal 256-colour palette, that you can see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93268/bash-ps1-256-colors-with-bold).

Comment: it is vim inside cygwin @Amadan.

Answer (score 1):

The numeric colors are ANSI escape codes based on xterm's 256 color map, seen here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg

There used to be only 8 colors (0 to 7): Black, Red, Green, Yellow, Blue, Magenta, Cyan, and White. The other 248 are defined as following:

```
0x08-0x0F:  high intensity colors
0x10-0xE7:  6 × 6 × 6 = 216 colors: 16 + 36 × r + 6 × g + b (0 ≤ r, g, b ≤ 5)
0xE8-0xFF:  grayscale from black to white in 24 steps
```

Information from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't decide anything about those colors.

It just tells the terminal emulator to use `DarkBlue` or `0`, without caring about the actual RGB values at all.